# Paypal button triggers "This form has expired" error

Tags: paypal

Freeform forms work just fine. Only the PayPal button gives me this error. Any ideas what's wrong?

Some answers to similar issues suggest disabling csrf protection (like so: $config['disable_csrf_protection']). But I have no idea where to do/try this.

I'm using the latest EE version (5.1.2)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally clear on the PayPal aspect here (would probably need to see more of your template code), but if you're just talking about disabling CSRF protection for forms handled by ExpressionEngine, and specifically using `$config['disable_csrf_protection'] = 'y';` then that is something you need to do in your ExpressionEngine config file.

From the docs:

> By default, ExpressionEngine’s system settings are managed in the Control Panel and stored in the database, but these settings can be overridden with one of 3 configuration files: the main configuration file, the site index file, and the CP index file.
>
> The main configuration file, found at system/user/config/config.php, is loaded every time the system is run, meaning that config overrides set in config.php always affect the system’s configuration.

https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/general/system_configuration_overrides.html

https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/general/system_configuration_overrides.html#disable-csrf-protection